# How to fix this error ''reader' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method''

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I am using a C# class.Everythink working fine but i am facing this error, so please help to fix this error.

```
     public void Filldropdownlist(DropDownList ddl, string DisplayVal, string Qstr)
{
    try
    {
        CreateConn();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Qstr, constr);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddl.Items.Clear();
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(DisplayVal, "none"));
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader(0).ToString(), reader(1).ToString()));
            ddl.DataTextField = reader(0).ToString();
            ddl.DataValueField = reader(1).ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConn();
    }
}
```

problem coming in inside the while loop.

Comment: Could you put the error above ?

Comment: 'reader' ais a variable but is used like a 'method'.please help..

Answer (score 2):

Indexing in C# is done with the `[]` operator, not with the `()` operator as in, for example Visual Basic.

In essence

```
reader(0)
```

means "call the method `reader` with and argument `0`" and

```
reader[0]
```

means give me value with the index `0` within the variable `reader`.

---

Aside from that, the `DataTextField` and the `DataValueField` are used only if you are data-binding the drop down, not if you are manually inserting the items, so those two lines can be omitted.

They are also incorect, because they need to be set to the **name** of the fields, not to their **values**

Answer (score 1):

Change like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
    {
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader[0].ToString(), reader(1).ToString()));
        ddl.DataTextField = reader[0].ToString();
        ddl.DataValueField = reader[1].ToString();
    }
```

use `[]` instead of `()`